# Not able to install AMQP Connector in MuleSoft Any point Studio

Tags: maven, amqp, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, stimulsoft

I am totally new to MuleSoft Any point Studio.

Trying to install AMQP Connector using the details provided on MuleSoft website.

[Link - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/amqp-connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/amqp-connector)

While adding maven support setting in pom.xml file, application throws error message.

Error Message : [image]

Currently I am using AnypointStudio-for-win-64bit-6.1.2 version.

**Setting that I need to add :**

To install the AMQP connector, add the following repository to your Maven installation:

```html
<repository>
  <id>mule-releases</id>
  <name>Mule Releases Repository</name>
  <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
  <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

```html
<inclusions>
  <inclusion>
  <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
  </inclusion>
</inclusions>
```

Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old but the answer is that you should add the inclusions within the 'configuration' tag. E.g.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
        <inclusions>
               <inclusion>
                      <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
                      <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
               </inclusion>
        </inclusions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In this way the amqp jar will be added to the deployed application.